# Do i need noise reduction algorithms while developing language model for my local language

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, noise-reduction, sphinx4

I am developing an acoustic model and an language model for my local language and I have planned to integrate it with pocketsphinx and sphinx4.

Now I want to ask do i need to implement an noise reduction algorithm for transmission accuracy for my local language or the pocketsphinx will take of that ? If yes I need to,  then what should be the steps I should follow for integrating the noise reduction algorithm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not *have to* use any noice reduction algorithms.

If you do use one, make sure you apply it to both the training audio and recognized audio. Otherwise you may notice a drop in accuracy.

Depending on the algorithm, you may be losing some important data if you use it. The sound may seem better for you, as a human, but it may become harder to recognize for Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary. Noise reduction is unrelated feature. If you do not have noise there is no need for noise reduction.

Comment: no I have noise , but i want to ask does noise reduction algorithm need to be modified dependent upon the language.

Comment: Probably you want to edit the original question then otherwise it's not quite clear what was your intent.